# Download files via batch with custom header

Tags: batch-file, download, header

Im trying to download tons of isochrones from an opentripplanner server.
Restriction is: no external tools or installations possible. Client is Windows 7. To create the .bat file i use a selfmade excel tool.

Default response is .json file format. This works just fine with bitsadmin:

```
bitsadmin /Transfer Download_Isochrone_1 /download /priority normal http://exampleserver.com/otp-rest-servlet/ws/isochrone?routerId=bordeaux^&algorithm=accSampling^&fromPlace=47.059,-0.880^&date=2013/10/01^&time=12:00:00^&maxWalkDistance=1000^&mode=WALK,TRANSIT^&cutoffSec=1800^&cutoffSec=3600 c:\username\downloads\Isochrone_1.json
bitsadmin /Transfer Download_Isochrone_2 /download /priority normal http://exampleserver.com/otp-rest-servlet/ws/isochrone?routerId=bordeaux^&algorithm=accSampling^&fromPlace=47.089,-0.881^&date=2013/10/01^&time=12:00:00^&maxWalkDistance=1000^&mode=WALK,TRANSIT&cutoffSec=1800^&cutoffSec=3600 c:\username\downloads\Isochrone_2.json
bitsadmin /Transfer Download_Isochrone_3 /download /priority normal http://exampleserver.com/otp-rest-servlet/ws/isochrone?routerId=bordeaux^&algorithm=accSampling^&fromPlace=47.159,-0.882^&date=2013/10/01^&time=12:00:00^&maxWalkDistance=1000^&mode=WALK,TRANSIT^&cutoffSec=1800^&cutoffSec=3600 c:\username\downloads\Isochrone_3.json
```

But .shp (.zip) is possible by using a custom header. ("Accept: application/x-zip-compressed"). Already done this via Browser-Plugin for a single isochrone.
So i tried

```
bitsadmin /Create /Download Download_Isochrones
bitsadmin /SetCustomHeader Download_Isochrones "Accept: application/x-zip-compressed"
bitsadmin /Addfile Download_Isochrones http://exampleserver.com/otp-rest-servlet/ws/isochrone?routerId=bordeaux^&algorithm=accSampling^&fromPlace=47.059,-0.880^&date=2013/10/01^&time=12:00:00^&maxWalkDistance=1000^&mode=WALK,TRANSIT^&cutoffSec=1800^&cutoffSec=3600 c:\username\downloads\Isochrone_1.txt
bitsadmin /Addfile Download_Isochrones http://exampleserver.com/otp-rest-servlet/ws/isochrone?routerId=bordeaux^&algorithm=accSampling^&fromPlace=47.089,-0.881^&date=2013/10/01^&time=12:00:00^&maxWalkDistance=1000^&mode=WALK,TRANSIT&cutoffSec=1800^&cutoffSec=3600 c:\username\downloads\Isochrone_2.txt
bitsadmin /Addfile Download_Isochrones http://exampleserver.com/otp-rest-servlet/ws/isochrone?routerId=bordeaux^&algorithm=accSampling^&fromPlace=47.159,-0.882^&date=2013/10/01^&time=12:00:00^&maxWalkDistance=1000^&mode=WALK,TRANSIT^&cutoffSec=1800^&cutoffSec=3600 c:\username\downloads\Isochrone_3.txt
bitsadmin /Resume Download_Isochrones
bitsadmin /Complete Download_Isochrones
```

But it doesnt work. Actually "/Addfile" seems to not work at all for this purpose. (using .txt extension for testing purposes)
Is it somehow possible to to combine /transfer with /setcustomheader or did i just do a mistake in the code above? Or is there any other possibilty to do this without win7-external tools?
In case of interest, heres the OpenTripPlanner doc: http://dev.opentripplanner.org/apidoc/1.0.0/resource_LIsochrone.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [winhttpjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/winhttpjs.bat):

```
call winhttpjs.bat "https://requestb.in/vp4p0gvp"  -headers-file headers.txt  -saveTo file.gzip
```

You'll need a headers.txt file in the same directory looking like:

```
#compression header
Accept: application/x-zip-compressed
```

To check the result I've created a a [test link](https://requestb.in/vp4p0gvp?inspect) on the https://requestb.in site.

Comment: Thanks, but not sure if im allowed to use it at my company. Anyway, tried at home but couldnt manage to make it work. Is there a documentation on how to use it?

Comment: @MrXsquared - only the help message though if you have issues you can ask me. There should be no problem to use this anywhere - it is not a binary and it is under MIT license.

Comment: downloaded winhhtpjs.bat and placed it on my desktop. copied your first code to a textfile.bat and your second code to a headers.txt. When executing the bat a cmd window pops up for less than a second. Also tried to change textfile.bat to "call D:\users\desktop\winhttpjs.bat "ht....". Same result. Running as administrator doesnt change things. Of course i also tried to run winhttpjs.bat itself. Also pops up for less than a second and closes. Running in powershell doesnt work as well. Maybe i should say im more into GIS than scripts :)

Comment: @MrXsquared  - try to set pause at the end of your script.Or try to run it from already opened seesion of command prompt.